# REST Get/ PostStandards

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I want to expose a WCF Rest method (using webHttpBinding) that takes a complex type as an in parameter. From past experience, I usually use POST/WebInvoke to pass complex params even if the method only return data without inserting/updating or modifing anything.

My question is: using POST for methods that only return data and just for passing a complex param break the REST "standards", and if yes are there any other alternatives.

Note: Serializing the param and passing it in the url with a WebGet/GET verb is not a viable solution because of the limited url size and other constraints.

Comment: I have to ask what you're doing that requires such "complex" params for a query...

Comment: I have to return a list of objects from a database, the complex params are the filter criterias that can be subtypes, arrays, ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is not really RESTful.

The verb has a meaning too.  `POST` means, basically, "add something under this resource".  If you're just doing a query, and not adding to a resource, you're misusing the verb.

Now, if the query is so complex that you need to pass a bunch of stuff to set it up...it could conceivably be a resource in its own right.  You could send a POST that would create the query, give it a URL, and then give you a link to view the query and/or its results.